# Is there an algorithm to find whether 2 combinators form a Turing-complete system?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus

It is known that `K = (λx.(λy.x))` and `S = (λx.(λy.(λz.((x z) (y z)))))` define a turing complete system, and we know procedures to map back and forth from lambda calculus to SK calculus. Now, given two arbitrary combinators, `A` and `B` in the set of valid lambda terms, is there an algorithm that will answer whether those combinators define a turing-complete system, and what is the corresponding mapping between a lambda term and those combinators? If not, is there such an algorithm with additional restrictions on the shape of `A` and `B` (say, its depth), that could be effectively used to find systems that are similar to SK?

Comment: Your question is ill-posed, and once it gets fixed it is not research-level. How are the combinators specified, by equations? If so, then there won't be an algorithm because a special case of what you're asking for will be the undecidable semigroup word problem.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I wonder if it helpful to be so aggressively negative towards the question. I think your comment could be turned into a nice answer.

Comment: As we say in Slovenia, I probably got up on my left leg.

Comment: It's probably undecidable even with one combinator, because you could encode an problem to a combinator such that you can't decide if it's halts or it reduces to some constant basis that is known to generate all combinators.

Comment: How the hell I am supposed to know it is or it is not research level? The fact I don't know the answer kinda implies I don't know the complexity. And getting up from your left leg is not an excuse to being aggressive against a questioner. This is a community. Fix your manners.

Comment: @Viclib: I think you need to fix your manners too.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question for cstheory. The word problem for (semi-)groups is probably not known in detail to most theoretical computer scientists and is not usually covered in undergraduate texts on group theory. The applicability of word problems to combinators would also be unclear to most CS folk.

Comment: Isn't this undecidable simply because of Rice's theorem?

Comment: I was completely well mannered until he attacked me, @DaveClarke .

Comment: Whether Andrej is right or not about the question, I don't think he was "agressive". There was no emotion in his comment, just a technical opinion about a question not being well-posed. Viclib, if you don't know enough about your question to know if it is research level, you should ask it at CS.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, I concede. But is it or is it not research level, after all?

Comment: The problem is definitely research-level, see e.g #6 of http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/, or http://www.win.tue.nl/rtaloop/problems/96.html

Comment: @cody: They are different problems from the current one.  The current question (after moving the phrase “given two arbitrary combinators A and B” to the appropriate position) is already answered by Emil’s comment, so I do not know what the OP is still waiting for.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I don't see how they are different; a procedure for verifying whether a finite set of combinators is combinatorially complete seems to be exactly what the OP is asking about. The problem statement specifies that it *is* decidable in the case of linear combinators.